# ViM resizing splits not working

Tags: vim

In the vim documentation at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-resize says I should use ctrl-W + to resize a split. However it is just not working. At this point I am wondering if I am pressing the buttons wrong.

I tried: 
pressing ctrl then w then + -> fail
pressing ctrl then shift W (because it was noted as a capital letter in docu)

I checked my .vimrc file keys are not remaped.

Specs: 
osx 10.8.4
vim 7.3 default installation
using default terminal.app

Comment: You must release `Ctrl` and `w` before you hit `+`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just remap it:

```
" resize window CTRL+(h|j|k|l)
noremap <C-j> :resize +1<CR>
noremap <C-k> :resize -1<CR>
noremap <C-h> :vertical resize -1<CR>
noremap <C-l> :vertical resize +1<CR>
```

Comment: These all ought to be `nnoremap`. Maps you posted here do not work from visual or select modes (not saying I can’t imagine why you need them in this modes) and are not motions for them to be defined in operator-pending mode.